# Capture a FAIL in a recipe in mingw32-make

Tags: makefile

My mingw32-make makefile works perfectly fine, but I'd like to do what would seem a TRIVIAL job to me, namely emit a beep when the final link FAILS.

My current recipe is trivial enough:

```
mydll.dll: $(RESFILE) $(OBJFILES)
    $(LINKCALL)
    @echo .
    @echo  ************************** DLL ok **************************
    @echo .
```

- it works perfectly fine. But I would like to capture a potential FAIL of the LINKCALL, and e.g. emit a beep.
  Just spent a few hours trying, but whatever else (but $(LINKCALL) ) I put into the 1st line of the recipe, appears to be sent VERBATIM to a CreateProcess, which is of course stupid - and fails.

Any idea how to detect a fail (and then take action on it) in mingw32-make?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every line in a recipe is executed by `sh`, so any shell based solution should work:

```
# On fail, echo failure string and exit with failure
$(LINKCALL) || (echo -e ".\n ***** DLL not ok *****\n." && exit 1)
```

Wrapping the $(LINKCALL) in a shell script should allow for a more readable solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

# do link call with args
if LINKCALL "$@"; then
  echo "success!"
else
  CODE=$?
  echo "fail"
  exit "$CODE"
fi
```

Comment: Too bad I'm too "junior" to upvote: your first solution is BRILLIANT, thanks so much!!
The second one also works, albeit it required some hacking as I'm in Win (i.e. no /bin/sh). As to how to emit a beep in a "DOS Box", should it help anybody, this does the trick: https://pastebin.com/zNYsysGc (in Notepad++, the character comes out as BEL).
Thanks again!